# JQuery nextAll for grabbing next element difficult functionality

Tags: jquery, scroll, css-selectors

We have a function involving a series of scrolling panels. The current item `li` in the middle of the panel has a class `.selected` and is represented by the variable $selectedLeft . That class is always passed to which ever `li` is in the middle after scroll.

What I want is for the next `li` to scroll the panel on click so that that element is in the middle. The function scrollTo is part of the make up of our function and works fine. The problem is with the selectors. At the moment which ever li you click on the function with selectors `$selectedLeft.nextAll('li').next().click( function()`  is taking over. The panel will not scroll up or down. That is supposed to only be if the `li` after the next `li` is clicked.

```
$selectedLeft.nextAll('li').click( function() {
                        myScroll2.scrollTo(0, 32, 200, true);

                    });
                    $selectedLeft.nextAll('li').next().click( function() {
                        myScroll2.scrollTo(0, 64, 200, true);

                    });
                    $selectedLeft.prevtAll('li').click( function() {
                        myScroll2.scrollTo(0, -32, 200, true);

                    });
                    $selectedLeft.prevAll('li').prev().click( function() {
                        myScroll2.scrollTo(0, -64, 200, true);

                    });
```

So regardless of how complex the set up is, the problem is with the selectors so I hope someone can see it. I tried adding `.eq(0)` and the entire function failed to do anything.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Marvellous

Nice Fiddle for you all http://jsfiddle.net/XHPYF/33/

Comment: It would be helpful to see the page, so we don't have to try to recreate this from scratch to solve.

Comment: This might be helpful. It does not work quite as well as the current one but will certainly illustrate the problem when you click on dates below the selected on http://jsfiddle.net/XHPYF/33/

Answer (score 0):

The selector isn't exactly the problem.

The jQuery object `$selectedLeft` is constantly changing, but the way you've wrote things only binds your scrolling events to the initial object. You need to `bind`or `delegate` your scrolls to all future `$selectedLeft`s.

Likewise, when `$selectedLeft` changes, you need to unbind the events from the previous one.

Another solution would be to check the index of the currently selected li and check whether the clicked on li is one or two elements away. (e.g. use `.eq() or array notation against the jQuery Object) This would clear up some of the "next" ambiguity.

Comment: Although that is true the .next() abiguity does not appear to be the problem. I set up an alert whereby it could tell me what the next() element was, prev(), next().next() and prev().prev() and the alert was correct every time.

Comment: In anycase, how would I achieve your method. Ive never used bind() controls